# QT How to create custom slot?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm creating my first GUI App in QT, I'm newbie at it.
This application is supposed to count calories for me with little more options than webapps offer me.
In my program I got 4 lineedits :

- lineEdit_Carbs
- lineEdit_Fats
- lineEdit_Protein
- lineEdit_Calories

I want to do like "Realtime counter", if user provides value to any of the 3 cells, carbs,fats,proteins it shows how many calories is it already.
I tried to do this

```
connect(ui->lineEdit_Carbs,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),ui->lineEdit_Calories,SLOT(setText(CALORIE_COUNT(ui->lineEdit_Carbs->text(),ui->lineEdit_Fats->text(),ui->lineEdit_Proteins->text()))))
```

CALORIE_COUNT function takes 3 arguments, 3 QStrings, returns calculated QString containing the calories.
I would have to do this connection 3 times, for each lineEdit containing macronutrient.
But this seem to not work because

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QLineEdit::setText(CALORIE_COUNT(ui->lineEdit_Carbs->text(),ui->lineEdit_Fats->text(),ui->lineEdit_Proteins->text())) in ..\CalcProto\mainwindow.cpp:22
```

It says there is no such slot.
How should I create slot to make it work?

Comment: I think you will need to create the three slots, one for each textChanged signal as you are just sending one QString.

Comment: you need to relay the signal. `textChanged(QString)` is just an event that informs a change. if you want to combine this new info(the `QString`) with other info and make some action, you do the combination in a intermediate slot and send a new signal form there to signal the action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connect(ui->lineEdit_Carbs,
        SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),
        this,
        SLOT(intermediateSlot()));//SLOT can ignore incoming arguments
```

---

```
private Q_SLOTS:
    intermediateSlot()
    {
     QString calorie = CALORIE_COUNT(ui->lineEdit_Carbs->text(),
                                     ui->lineEdit_Fats->text(),
                                     ui->lineEdit_Proteins->text());
     ui->lineEdit.setText(calorie);// you can emit a new signal here
                                   // carring calorie and connect it to
                                   // ui->lineEdit, which is more Qt-ish
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe can subclass QLineEdit and reimplement the `setText()` method, but I am not sure you can, since it not seems to be declared as virtual

What about connecting all the QLineEdit `textChanged(QString)` to the the same slot and do all the work in it ?

Something like

```
connect(ui->lineEdit_Carbs,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), UpdateCalc);
connect(ui->lineEdit_Calories,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), UpdateCalc);
connect(ui->lineEdit_Fats,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), UpdateCalc);
connect(ui->lineEdit_Proteins,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), UpdateCalc);
```

where the UpdateCalc slot do all the calculations ?

Eventually you can add a timer to add a little delay to the execution so if you insert something with more than one char, you don't fire the event every time.

Comment: I wouldnt do a timer, it seems to be way harder and It will lead to little more complication, because if the user enters custom calorie value it will rewrite it and do the calculation anyway. If the SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)) have the QString inside it means SLOT has to take it as an argument? Is there a way to omit it?

Comment: connect(ui->lineEdit_Carbs, &QLineEdit::textChanged, UpdateCalc); could work.

Comment: You could still use it like that, if you don't specify the SLOT to be expecting a QString, the value from the signal will just be ignored.